Gluing trajectories in Floer theory
The gluing theorem for broken trajectories (in the sense of Prop 9.2.3 in Audin-Damian's Floer theory book), is only stated for when the index difference is 2 ($\mu(x)=\mu(y)+1=\mu(z)+2$).
At first I thought this is because it is all that is needed to prove that the differential of the Floer complex indeed satisfies $\partial^2=0$. But in Audin-Damian, the results in Section 8 regarding the Fredholm index is stated in general, so it is strange that they retsirct to index difference 2 only for this proposition. However I fail to see why Audin-Damian's proof would not work if $\mu(x),\mu(y),\mu(z)$ are arbitrary.
Knowing that the Floer case is much harder than the Morse analogue, I would like to ask if the analogous statement for higher index difference can be found anywhere.
Perhaps more general statements can be found in references dealing with Lagrangian Floer homology, but I am very new to Floer theory and had trouble looking for this statement in more complicated settings.
